# Auto-complete spinner in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have got an edit text where I want that when someone insert her values it will narrow his option's  .
the options are stored in a DB (up to 1200 values to one editbox ).

i cant get the concept of how to do it can someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)...You'll need a Cursor Adapter for it.

Here's an [example](http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/autocompletetextview-cursoradapter-t12430.html)

If you need to enter multiple Values into the textbox, use a [MultiAutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html)...Works with Tokens.

Hope it helps!